# Flex : Pass parameters across multiple applications

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Is there any way we can pass parameters from one flex application to the other flex application ?

I know we can pass parameters from module to application and vice versa.

Thanks
Sumukh

Answer (score 2):

If both applications are running at the same time on the same machine, you could open up a LocalConnection between the two applications to send information between them. See the [LocalConnection documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html?flash/net/LocalConnection.html&flash/net/class-list.html) for more info.